# Is there a plugin which let's me select windows by keyboard hint?

Tags: unity, gnome, compiz

I'm looking for a method which let's me select windows by keyboard hint (kinda how vimperator highlights links, but for the windows on my screen). Ideally, it'd first scale the windows then show me the hints, then typing the hint switches to the window.

Any thing out there?

Comment: Alt tab ? doesn't cut it?

Comment: It works, but isn't ideal. I frequently have 4 or more windows open and rolling through them adds noise to my workflow. I'd prefer to be more direct about which window I want without using the mouse.

Answer (score 1):

With "Scale Window Title Filter" you can select windows by typing parts of the window title in the "Scale" view.

Activate "Scale Addons" and set "Appearance" -> "Window Title" "Window Title Display" to "All windows" to have *Scale* displaying window titles for all windows.

Comment: Awesome. Note to get the title filter one must install the ``compiz-plugins-extra`` package. Quick follow up, do you know of a global way to control my window titles? For instance, if I spawn 3 terminals, is it possible to append T1, T2, and T3 to their title?